# Why does Blender say, "No more keyframes to jump to in this direction"?

Tags: keyframes, timeline

Sometimes while editing keyframes I'll see this message when attempting hotkey to the next or previous keyframe: **"No more keyframes to jump to in this direction."** The timeline is full of keyframes, so why does Blender think otherwise? Thanks. Blender 3.3.0, Windows 11

[image: example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is showing all keyframes, but jumping only to the next one for the active object and when there are no more keyframes for it, it reports that.